# will static compilation break the ABI?

Tags: c++, regex, boost, backwards-compatibility, abi

I want to provide a library which will do some regex things, and since either gcc nor clang (correct me if I'm wrong) implements it now, I will use boost for this. 
But boost breaks its ABI from time to time so my question is:

Is it safe to compile my library with the static compiled version of boost, so that no ABI break will occur in future versions of boost?

Comment: C++ does have [regular expressions in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) these days.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Not implemented in gcc (libstdc++ if you wanna be pedantic).

Comment: If you can't use C++11, there is also system calls `regcomp`, `regexec` etc used by `grep` and `egrep`. Not as powerful as Boost's but may be good enough and should be stable.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I know that c++11 provides a regex header, but libstdc++ does not implement it yet.

Comment: It depends on what version of GCC you are using. Some of it exists in version 4.6, version 4.7 is pretty good and 4.8 is best of course.

Comment: Just so you know, the thing boost MAY change is the API (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface), and not the ABI (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) which is defined by the compiler you use rather than the code you are compiling.

Comment: Do you provide a static (*.a/*.lib) or a dynamic (*.so/*.dll) library?

Comment: In case of a dynamic lib there shouldn't be any problem, if you don't export `boost` types. As for static lib, the user of your lib, who links it to his app, must use the same boost version as your lib does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compile statically with boost you won't have any ABI problems with future versions, since nothing is called "externally", you also won't be using anything from future versions without recompilation obviously.

I've statically linked with boost for years, mainly for easier deployment, without any problems.

Comment: Hmm, it sounds legit to me and I thought the same way. But since no other has proven your answer, I will not accept it.